# Can I implement a managed COM-visible interface in unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have a class implemented in C# that I want to use from a native application. The C# class has a dependency described by an interface, which is exepected to be delivered by the code instantiating the class. I would like to realize this interface in the native application and pass it to the C# object via COM. Strongly simplified, the C# code looks like this:

```csharp
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("910E8445-7A62-403F-BAEE-17AB0C169CA8")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IComWidget
{
   void SetClient(IComWidgetClient client);
   void DoStuff();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("850F3EBB-CD18-4E16-881F-50B50DD5AEB0")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IComWidgetClient
{
  int GetValue();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("86B9EC33-6CDF-438F-9A67-57D009723027")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class ComWidget : IComWidget
{
   private IComWidgetClient m_Client;

   public void DoStuff()
   {
      var i = m_Client.GetValue();
      Debug.WriteLine("value was {0}", i);
   }

   public void SetClient(IComWidgetClient client)
   {
      m_Client = client;
   }
}
```

The native application loads the COM library as a side-by-side assembly with a proper manifest, and implements the `IComWidgetClient` interface. It *seems* to work, but when running automated tests on the system several tests fail with an unhandled ExecutionEngineExecption. The way it fails (the test process is aborted) smells like some kind of corruption during garbage collection.
I think I may be able to write a managed c++ unit test that mimics the steps that lead to the error. At least it fails the same way. The test looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
void TestStuff()
{
   IComWidgetPtr sut = NULL;
   NativeClient* client = NULL;

   try
   {
      sut = IComWidgetPtr(__uuidof(ComWidget));
      client = new NativeClient();

      IComWidgetClient* pvObject;
      client->QueryInterface(IID_IComWidgetClient, (void**)&pvObject);

      sut->SetClient(pvObject);

      sut->Release();

      GC::Collect();
      GC::WaitForPendingFinalizers();

      Assert::IsTrue(true); // If we get this far, everything went OK...
   }
   finally
   {
      sut = NULL;
      delete client;
      client = NULL;
   }
};
```

Where `NativeClient` is a simple native object implementing IComWidgetClient

```
public class NativeClient: IComWidgetClient
{
   ...
}
```

What goes wrong? Is what I am trying to do at all possible?

Full source code can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-D57qCpESa5MnpZUXZRN2pyNnc/view?usp=sharing